# Why won't my Logitech F310 controller work on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, games

I have recently tried to play games from the Ubuntu store with my Logitech F310 pc controller, and have had problems. I used WINE to use the program Joy2Key and make my controller emulate keyboard commands, but it did not work. Let me clarify, it did work, but not with the games. My video game man spun in a circle when I tried to move where he was pointed, and then the mouse popped out of the side of the game pannel, which does not normally happen when I use the mouse. I don't know about any other programs that would function the same as Joy2Key. Does anybody have a solution to my problem or an alternative software that is build for Ubuntu 16.04?

Update, I want to use the controller for non-Steam games. I also need this controller to emulate mouse movements.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this link already : http://nomoreterminals.blogspot.kr/2013/12/how-to-set-up-logitech-f310-on-ubuntu.html ??

I hope you try installing your contoller driver ?? If you would be able to install the driver of your controller then I think it should work directly there is no need of Joy2Key.

Comment: I didn't find that article yet, but I'll try and see if it works.

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: What problem you faced while installation/configuring ??